# TowerJS without CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, towerjs, coffeekup

I'm just looking at the possibilities in Node.js web development. I'm used to coding in ASP.NET MVC 3, so TowerJS and Geddy looks friendly and familiar to me (because of the MVC pattern)

However I don't really like CoffeeScript (because of its strange syntax and the debugging issues), so I would be happy if I could use Tower without using CoffeeScript - and if I could use simple JavaScript instead. Is it possible? If I go to their website, I see CoffeeScripts everywhere...

(I would be happy, if I also could use another templating engine (because CoffeeKup uses CoffeeScript as well), and I change it into a more [Razor-like engine](https://github.com/cstivers78/bliss/wiki).)

Comment: You should be able too... I've never used TowerJS but have you tried using it with just JS?

Comment: Now that I read on the TowerJS page it seems that all the workflow is intended for Coffeescript, even the use of cake for minimizing etc. Try http://railwayjs.com/, it seems similar to TowerJS in philosophy.

Comment: Give CoffeeScript a try, you won't regret it. Don't be afraid of changes in your life ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Tower development is done using coffeescript. A javascript api is planned for the future, though I don't know how far off that is. There are a few complications to work out, before that will be possible.

EDIT: Adding a Javascript API to Tower has become a priority for the framework, so I expect this to come to fruition sooner than I had anticipated when I originally answered. Probably quite soon.

Comment: Was the JavaScript support added?

Comment: @GuyKorland still in progress. You can keep see some of the most recent discussion around that here: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/pull/299#issuecomment-10677833 because of the way in which Tower's api was originally designed (around CoffeeScript's executable class bodies), it's been quite a bit more work than I think anyone ever anticipated to untangle from. In the meantime, Tower is an amazing framework and I'd encourage you and anyone else to go ahead and try it. Coffeescript is incredibly simple to get used to, and Tower makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should give Geddy a try then. http://geddyjs.org